# How do I use the SSRS lookup function to properly calculate a sum of data from another table?

Tags: reporting-services

I am attempting to sum the values of data from one table within another table in SSRS.

This is the formula I have in the source table which is working as expected.

=SUM(IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Non-GMWB Total", Fields!Account_total_value.Value, 0))

This is the formula I have in the destination table.

=SUM(IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Non-GMWB Total", Lookup(Fields!Account_ID.Value, Fields!Account_ID.Value, Fields!Account_total_value.Value, "accounts"), 0))

The total from this formula does not match the total generated by the formula in the source table.

[image]
[image]